# Is there an rx operator that merges streams, but one stream at a time?

Tags: ios, swift, merge, rx-swift

I would like to merge two `observable` streams into one, just like you do with the `.merge()` operator. The reason I don't use that operator is because it runs the `observables` at the same time. I need an operator that merges two streams, but finish the first before it starts with the second one, so that the response would be something like: `"stream1Value1", "stream1Value2", "stream2Value1", "stream2Value2".`

Using the `.merge()` operator, the code looks lie this:

```
Observable.merge(self.getParameter(id: id).asObservable(), self.getSecondaryParameter(id: id).asObservable()).asSingle()
```

but gives me an output like this:
`"stream1Value1", "stream2Value1", "stream1Value2", "stream2Value2".`

I have tried using `Single.zip()` but this gives me two `parameters` to work with ($0 and $1). Also I'm not sure if it finishes the first before starting with the second...

Comment: I am not familiar with the RX syntax in Swift, but I believe you could modify the second stream with the skipUntil operator - in JS it would be `stream2$.skipUntil(stream1$.pipe(last()))` — and then merge that with stream1.

Comment: `skip(until:)` is what it's called in RxSwift. That would not work though (even in RxJS I suspect) because both `stream1$` and `stream2$` would still start at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn more about all the combining operators in RxSwift in my article [Recipes for Combining Observables in RxSwift](https://danielt1263.medium.com/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f).

The operator you are looking for is called `concat`. There is a method as well as several static function overloads.

Look in the "Concat.swift" file in the library for the various versions of the operator as well as their documentation.

BTW, the `zip` operator, as well as `combineLatest`, also start both Observables at the same time.